# The Lindelöf space of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I wonder to know what sets different types of compact subspaces in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the standard topology are.

I already solve for compact sets, countably compact sets, sequentially compact sets, limits point compact sets, which are closed and bounded.

But I fail for the Lindelöf subspaces.

Some clues will be grateful.Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Assuming the axiom of countable choice, every second-countable topological space is Lindelöf.  Furthermore, every subspace of a second-countable space is second-countable.  Since $\Bbb{R}^n$ is second-countable, it follows that every subspace of $\Bbb{R}^n$ is Lindelöf.  If you want counter-examples in models of ZF in which the axiom of countable choice does'nt hold - the question should be reclassified as a question in set-theory, not general-toplogy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an arbitrary subset $A\subset(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathcal{T}_{\mathbb{R}^n})$, we intend to prove that $A$ is Lindelöf.
we need two lemmas.

A $\mathrm{C}_2$ space is Lindelöf.

Second-countability is hereditary.

A brief proof for the first lemma is as follows.
Let $(X,\mathcal{T})$ be a $\mathcal{T}_2$ space and let $\mathcal{B}={B_n\colon n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be a countable basis of $(X,\mathcal{T})$.
Consider an open cover $\mathcal{U}=\{U_i\colon i\in I\}$.
Define $J\subset\mathbb{N}$ by $n\in J$ if and only if there exists $U\in\mathcal{U}$ such that $B_n\subset U$.
As a subset of $\mathbb{N}$, $J$ is a countable set and for every $n\in J$ the set $\mathcal{U}_n=\{U\in\mathcal{U}\colon B_n\subset U\}$ is non-empty, by definition of $J$.
From the axiom of choices, it follows that there is a function $f:J\to\cup_n\mathcal{U}_n$ such that $f(n)\in\mathcal{U}_n$ for all $n\in J$.
For any $x\in X$, there exists $U_x\in\mathcal{U}$ containing $x$, as $\mathcal{U}$ is a cover of $X$.
By definition of basis, we have $x\in B_{n_x}\subset U_x$, for some $n_x\in\mathbb{N}$.
Thus, $n_x\in J$ and $f(n_x)\in\mathcal{U}_{n_x}$.
Consequently, $x\in B_{n_x}\subset f(n_x)\in\mathcal{U}'$, which implies that $\mathcal{U}'=\{f(n)\colon n\in J\}$ is a countable subcover of $X$ indexed by $J$.

The second lemma is obvious by taking the subspace topology.

Now we prove the conclusion.
For an arbitrary subset $A\subset(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathcal{T}_{\mathbb{R}^n})$, since $\mathrm{C}_2$ is hereditary, $A$ also satisfies $\mathrm{C}_2$ axiom.
In light of the second lemma, $A$ is Lindelöf.